# Get apache/php to give a response to any URL

Tags: php, apache

I've tried searching but can't find anything. I would like apache/php to be able to return a response to any URL without having to have a PHP page that exists. eg, with URLs like below I don't want to create a page for each URL, I would just like to have 1 php page that queries a database underneath. The php code would somehow get the filename as a parameter so it could make decisions on that. Is that possible?

`http://myserver/file20180401.csv
http://myserver/file20180402.csv`

Comment: google for mod_rewrite

Comment: Create a custom PHP script to use as a 404 page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use mod_rewrite. Just paste this into your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?file=$1 [NC]
```

Then simply in your `index.php` file (or whichever you would like to change it to) use some simple PHP code:

```
$file = $_GET['file'];
echo $file;
```

In your example `http://myserver/file20180401.csv` the variable `$file` would be equal to `file20180401.csv`.

**EDIT:** Repeating here as didn't come out well in comment.
This was the solution I ended up using as the apache docs recommend for performance reasons to place it in the httpd.conf file instead of .htaccess file:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/test_transporter>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*\.csv)$ file.php?file=$1 [NC]
</Directory>`
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I had to add `RewriteEngine on` and I ended up putting it in the httpd.conf file as that is what the apache documentation recommended' Not sure if this will come out in a comment but here is the full text `<Directory "/var/www/html/test_transporter>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*\.csv)$ file.php?file=$1 [NC]
</Directory>`